# Retrieve selected object from select field

Tags: knockout.js

I have a drop-down list being populated by the "options" binding and would like to be able to retrieve the currently selected object from the options list on the change event.

For example, if the selected option is changed to UK I would like to be able to access the UK Country object from the getValue method as illustrated:

```
var Country = function(name, population, countrytype) {
    this.countryName = name;
    this.countryPopulation = population;
    this.countryType = countrytype;
    this.selected = ko.observable( false );
};        

var viewModel = {
    getValue: function( item ) {
        // set selected item's "selected" observable to true and the other items of the same countryType to false
        console.log( 'Item: ', item );
    },
    availableCountries : ko.observableArray([
        new Country("UK", 65000000, 'en'),
        new Country("USA", 320000000, 'en'),
        new Country("Sweden", 29000000, 'sv'),
        new Country("Test 1", 29000000, 'sv'),
        new Country("Test 2", 29000000, 'de'),
        new Country("Test 3", 29000000, 'de')
    ]),
    getByType : function( areaLabel ) {
        var results = [];

        ko.utils.arrayForEach( this.availableCountries(), function( item ) {
            if ( item.countryType === areaLabel ) {
                results.push( item );
            }
        });

        return results;
    },
    selectedCountry : ko.observable() // Nothing selected by default
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/dJFLW/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that what you want to do ? http://jsfiddle.net/dJFLW/3/

If it is so, you don't need the `getValue` function, you can access which country has been selected with `selectedCountry`. What you forgot is to set the `value` binding in the select HTML element:

```
<select data-bind="options: availableCountries,
                   optionsText: 'countryName',
                   value: selectedCountry"></select>

<span data-bind="text: selectedCountry().countryName"></span>
```

Also, two things:

1. "countryName" and "countryPopulation" are not observable properties, maybe they should not be, just be careful.
2. You don't need the "selected" property in your Country class.

Comment: Shoot. Beat me to it! So to be perfectly clear @hereswhatidid, your getValue method would contain `console.log( 'Item: ', viewModel.selectedCountry().countryName);`.

Comment: @Jayayn, for his implementation countryName and countryPopulation do *not* need to be observable. Unless, of course, there's some reason outside of this code that they would need to be.

Comment: @Grinn well I just refreshed the questions on knockoutJS and his question was there since 7 seconds only :-) Also, I agree, it does not necessarily need to be an observable, I just wanted to mention it.

Comment: The problem is that I do need to use the "selected" property as this array of objects is being used elsewhere and that property is in play.  I'll edit the question with that information.

Comment: The problem is that you do not associate any "value" binding in your lists, which means that you cannot know which item is properly selected (I mean, not with Knockout, you could by inspecting the select box items). The "item" parameter of the "getValue" function is in fact the entire view model. I just created a selectedC1 value to hold the item that has been selected, and then I modified your "getValue" function. Check out here: http://jsfiddle.net/dJFLW/5/

Comment: @hereswhatidid so, did jsfiddle.net/dJFLW/5 solve the problem ?

Comment: @Jalayn: If he really needs the `.selected` property, he could always have`selectedCountry.subscribe` in there that updates the `.selected` property of the currently selected entry. But, if he can get `selectedCountry` to work, that definitely would be better.

Comment: Unfortunately (for me) this does appear to be the only workable method.  Thanks!